# Running multiple different processes on Heroku

Tags: heroku

I have been searching all over the Internet but I can't seem to find an answer to my exact problem.

I have a ruby script that runs using an argument. E.g Append.rb

If I call ruby Append.rb 0  - this will start a thread and do some logic

If I call ruby Append.rb 2000 - this will start a new thread and do a different logic

If I set up a Procfile, and run locally using 'fromen start' both scripts are triggered at the same time and it works ok.

The Procfile looks like this:

worker: ruby Append.rb 0

worker: ruby Append.rb 1000

If I do the same thing in Heroku, it will start 2 dynos, but both will trigger:

Append.rb 1000

Any ideas how I can solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Anything aside from `web` is just an abritrary string which identifies that process, it doesn't need to be called `worker`.  However, that string does need to be unique.  Therefore, just call it something different:

```
worker_0: ruby Append.rb 0
worker_1000: ruby Append.rb 1000
```

Then you can use these identifiers in your scale commands:

```
heroku ps:scale worker_0+1
heroku ps:scale worker_1000=1
```

and so on.  For more Procfile info, see here:  http://neilmiddleton.com/the-procfile-is-your-friend/